# Android child view being null within onActivityResult in parents activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my Android application there is a view, 'manage players', and within that there is an 'add player' view. On the 'add player' view I am accessing the camera, so I have an override on onActivityResult. When it hits this, within the 'manage players' activity, the 'add player' view is now null. Here is a sample of the code:

```
public class ManagePlayersActivity {

    private AddPlayerView addPlayerView = null;
    private ManagePlayersView view;
    private Context context;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;

    view = ManagePlayersViewFactory.create(this);
    setContentView(view.asView());

        public void onEvent(ClickEvent event) {
            final Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
            ManagePlayersActivity.this.addPlayerView = AddPlayerViewFactory.create(context);

            ManagePlayersActivity.this.addPlayerView.setButtonPhotoPickerOnClickListener(new EventListener<ClickEvent>() {
                public void onEvent(ClickEvent event) {

                    ManagePlayersActivity.this.addPlayerView.setPlayerPhoto("Setting Photo");

                    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

                    if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    }                   
                }

            });

            d.show();
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ManagePlayersActivity.this.addPlayerView.setPlayerPhoto("Photo set");
        } 
    }
}
}
```

So, after doing that the addPlayerView is null in the onActivity result. In honesty, I am very new to Android and Java, I am a c# web developer with no experience in MVC, so it could be a misunderstanding of how it fundamentally works. But, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this line above the event handler(i.e., outside onEvent()):

ManagePlayersActivity.this.addPlayerView = AddPlayerViewFactory.create(context);

Comment: Brilliant thanks. That stops it being null. The problem now though is that the view is no longer open, and goes back to the parent view, with the 'add player' view closed. Is this a simple change, as part of this, or is it a wider problem?

Comment: is the camera not getting called or the entire view not opening?